# Adding additional content/markup to a drupal render array

Tags: php, drupal-7

This is my first question on here--though I've used it for years for reference--so, please forgive me if this is trivial/already answered, but I wasn't able to find a solution.

I have a render array being returned to the 'content' attribute of a block view array. I'm just returning a table as of right now.

```
<?php
$data = array(
'#markup' => theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows)),
);

return $data;
?>
```

What I'd like to do is add additional markup at the beginning. I've tried adding a '#prefix' attribute, but the results weren't as expected; I ended up with HTML outside of the block. Anything else I thought would work seems to cause PHP errors or do nothing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using HTML tags with #prefix they should be closed with #suffix.
Did you remember to close the content in #prefix?

Like so:

```
$data = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#prefix' => '<div>',
    '#markup' => theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows)),
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

**Edit**

To control the output as HTML rather than a render array one could use the hook_block_view() hook to feed the $block['content'] with pure HTML rather than a render array.
[According to the documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) the $block['content'] can handle both types of input.

```
function modulename_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();

  switch($delta) {
    case 'block_name' :
      $block['content'] = '<div>Content before</div>';
      $block['content'] .= theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
      $block['content'] .= '<div>Content after</div>';
    break;
  }

  return $block;
}
```

If you don't want to use the block view hook I guess you could render your render arrays in this manner instead:

```
$render_array = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows)),
);

$before = '<div>Content before</div>';
$after = '<div>Content after</div>';
$data = $before.render($render_array).$after;
return $data;
```

See [render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7) for a reference.
Also remember to clear your caches like stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5168175/1904615).

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I understand what you're saying, but I was trying to use prefix for a different purpose; the purpose is what I need help with: To add more html to the block, in addition to the theme rendered table. I do appreciate the effort though.

What I'd like to do is, say, add some text before or after the table in the block.

Comment: Ah, I see. - I edited my answer to try to reflect your refinement.